# Вопрос по дизайну в HTML

Tags: html, дизайн, css

Можно какими нибудь CSS средствами реализовать оформление границ блока изображением, а углы этого блока другой маленькой картинкой ?

Если возможно, то как ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`border-image`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/border-image)

> Используется для отображения рисованной рамки вокруг элемента. Толщина рамки задаётся свойством border, при этом если указано border: 0, то рамка не выводится. При других значениях border рисунок всегда имеет приоритет. Фон, если он задан через свойство background, отображается под рамкой.

Comment: Спасибо, сайт хороший, знаю ) Как-то пропустил этот атрибут... очень полезный, спасибо )